# When to use "necropsy" instead of "autopsy"?

Tags: synonyms

I came across the following in an article about dove hunting:

> ...the study recorded the hits and misses of 5,094 shots with size 6
>   and 7 steel shot and 7 1/2 lead shot, killing a total of 1,146 doves,
>   1,100 of which were necropsied.

After looking this up it seems *necropsy* is another way of saying that an autopsy was performed; the body was examined after death.

When should we prefer one to the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll notice that your quote is about dead birds.  That's why the verbal form of "necropsy" was used.  An autopsy is performed on human remains; a necropsy, on non-human animal remains.  This [veterinarian site](http://veterinary.answers.com/veterinary-medicine/necropsy-versus-autopsy-similarities-and-differences) explains in detail.

Comment: I love that @deadrat is answering a question about necropsy.

Comment: Your username fits in to that sentence quite nicely too...

Comment: If we ever get a question about taxidermy, maybe StuffedDeadRat will answer.